# Difference between emission and conjuring

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

Alright I've basically finished the existing manga and anime and I'm still confused. What's the difference between an emitter and a conjurer? What can each do that the other can't?

Answer (score 4):

[Emmiters](https://hunterxhunter.fandom.com/wiki/Nen#Emission) are Nen users who are adept at separating their Auras from their bodies and using it for a variety of functions. Some examples being [Leorio](https://hunterxhunter.fandom.com/wiki/Leorio_Paradinight) (who could emit his aura into creating a warmhole for carrying attacks). Emitters are also capable of transforming the separated Aura to look like certain shapes and objects. [Pokkle](https://hunterxhunter.fandom.com/wiki/Pokkle) for example, (renowned for using his Nen to take the shape of bow and arrow which he could use for offense).

[image]

While [Conjurers](https://hunterxhunter.fandom.com/wiki/Nen#Conjuration) on the other hand, have the ability to create physical objects using Aura. More adept Conjurers can even create laws and principles which are affixed to the object manifested from their Aura. An example being [Kurapika's](https://hunterxhunter.fandom.com/wiki/Kurapika) conjured "Dowsing chains" which were created with a principle of detecting lies and Aura.

Comment: Can emitters not emit objects?

Comment: Emitters can only release Auras @Orion. Only Conjurers are able to create objects with their Auras. There have been various combinations with the 6 types but normally, only a conjurer can emit objects from their Aura.

Comment: The Emitters Aura could also  resemble  an object, eg: Pokkes Nen arrows, note thou that the aura only takes the shape of arrows. However, conjurers create the actual material object from imagination using their Nen

Comment: I think it's also notable that a non-nen user can see a conjured object but cannot see emitted aura. (e.g. Kortopi's items were visible to everyone but Pokke's Nen arrows couldn't be seen by most the ants)